# How to traverse just the first level of <LI> elements `with no class tag`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I am new to web developement and stuck at one place. I need to traverse just the first level LI elements. I have tried but I end up traversing the children too. below is my attempt. I just want to display the first level `LI` elements. Below is what I acheived.

```
<div id = jsTree>
<ul>
   <li id="1" class="root">
      Menu Items
      <ul></ul>
   </li>
   <li id="4"  class="root">
      Menu Items
      <ul>
         <li id="3" >
            Test 1
            <ul></ul>
         </li>
         <li id="7">
            Test 2
            <ul></ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="2"  class="root">
      Hidden Items
      <ul></ul>
   </li>
   <li id="5"  class="root">
      Hidden Items
      <ul></ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
<button id = btnSubmit>Click me</button>

 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
       $( ".root" ).each(function( index ) {
 alert($(this).text());
});
    });
```

Above code traverses just the first level but captures the children too in the alert box. I just want to display the first level `LI`.
I am thinking there must be multiple ways to do it. But I am looking for good/simple way that a beginner will understand.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/L0vuqvqt/1/)

**EDIT**

Actually the HTML that's getting generated in kind of dynamic and I do not have much control over it. I looked into the debugger and found that I do not have any `class = "root"` attached to my HTML.

[Working Fiddle Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/L0vuqvqt/4/)

But I want the same result when `class = root` is not attached. So how to loop using `each` when `class = root` is not there and still be able to get the same result.

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "jsTree">
<ul>
   <li id="1">
      Menu Items
      <ul></ul>
   </li>
   <li id="4">
      Menu Items
      <ul>
         <li id="3" >
            Test 1
            <ul></ul>
         </li>
         <li id="7">
            Test 2
            <ul></ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="2">
      Hidden Items
      <ul></ul>
   </li>
   <li id="5">
      Hidden Items
      <ul></ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
<button id = "btnSubmit">Click me</button>

 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
      // WHAT TO PUT HERE
       $( WHAT TO PUT HERE ).each(function( index ) {
        alert($(this).contents().not($(this).children()).text());
});
    });
```

Comment: So the problem is the text() is selecting the children elements and not just the text nodes?

Comment: yes, it selects the children texts too even it traverses just the first level of `li`. But I just want to display the first level `LI` elements. No children text.

Comment: `<div id = jsTree>` should have `"` around the id. like this `<div id = "jsTree">` and `<button id = btnSubmit>` should be like `<button id = "btnSubmit">`

Comment: @epascarello: where can I get the answer then. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you click the link on the duplicate? Look at the first or second answer, they explain how to only get the text. replace the `$("#foo").` with `$(this)` and paste the code inside of your forEach loop

Comment: @epascarello  Got it to working. You rock. Thank you so so much sir!

Comment: complete hack... https://jsfiddle.net/L0vuqvqt/3/

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Are you making a drop down menu or something else? To only show top level, you can display block the ul li elements first-child and hide all that are ul li ul.

Comment: @epascarello : I am sorry I had to updat my question. can you please look into it. NATH: I need the text of first level of all LI elements. I need to do some string match/check on basis of that.

Comment: @NathanielFlick: can you see my edit..